# Animating a 2D MDOF system

Tags: graphics

I'm studying mechanical engineering and I have to complete an assignment of animating a 2D graphic of a two degree of freedom system response presented on the picture below.
[image]
I've calculated the response of the system in the code below:

```
kt1 = 3000(*Nm/rad*);
kt2 = 2000(*Nm/rad*);
L1 = 3(*m*);
L2 = 4(*m*);
L3 = 5(*m*);
m1 = 50(*kg*);
m2 = 70(*kg*);
m3 = 100(*kg*);
g = 9.81(*m/s^2*);

J1 = (m1 L1^2)/3;
Jt2 = (m2 L2^2)/12;
Jt3 = (m3 L3^2)/12;

sol = NDSolve[{J1 (\[Phi]1'')[
      t] == ((4 kt2 L1^2 - 2 kt1 L3) \[Phi]1[t] + 
     2 (2 kt2 L1 (2 + L2) + kt1 L3) \[Phi]2[t] + 
     L1 (L1 (2 Jt3 - 2 L3 m2 + L3^2 m3) (\[Phi]1'')[
          t] + L2 (2 Jt3 - L3 m2 + 
           L3^2 m3) (\[Phi]2'')[t]))/(2 L3),
   Jt2 (\[Phi]2'')[t] == 
    1/(4 L3) ((8 kt2 L1 L2 + 4 kt1 L3 - 2 kt2 L1 L3) \[Phi]1[t] + 
       2 (kt2 (2 + L2) (4 L2 - L3) - 2 kt1 L3) \[Phi]2[t] + 
       L2 (2 L1 (2 Jt3 - L3 m2 + L3^2 m3) (\[Phi]1'')[
            t] + L2 (4 Jt3 - L3 m2 + 
             2 L3^2 m3) (\[Phi]2'')[t])),
   \[Phi]1[0] == 0.1, \[Phi]2[0] == 0.2, \[Phi]1'[0] == 
    0.5, \[Phi]2'[0] == 0},
  {\[Phi]1[t], \[Phi]1'[t], \[Phi]1''[t], \[Phi]2[t], \[Phi]2'[
    t], \[Phi]2''[t]},
  {t, 0, 500, 0.001}, Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta", 
  MaxSteps -> Infinity]
```

I'm interested in x-y motion so naturally I first have to convert the coordinates:

```
Yt2 = L1 \[Phi]1''[t] + (L2 \[Phi]2''[t])/2;
Yt3 = (L3 \[Phi]3''[t] )/2;
\[Phi]3[t] = -((L1 \[Phi]1[t] + L2 \[Phi]2[t])/2);
\[Phi]3''[t] = -((L1 \[Phi]1''[t] + L2 \[Phi]2''[t])/2);
```

This is where my problem occurs as I have little experience in animating 2D motion.  The animation can be minimalistic without the torsion springs included. So id just need two support as shown in the picture and 3 beams that I would assign functions of motion to. My question is if such an animation of the system in the picture is possible in mathematica. And if possible how would i go about making such an animation(which function to use, are there any tutorials out there).

Edit: I fixed a typo and replaced graphic of the model with a more accurate graphic that shows angular displacements and coordinate system.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Can you please show on your diagram how exactly are the coordinate system and the angles (φ1, φ2 and φ3) defined?

Comment: Also, take a look at this simple example of `Animate`. 

`Animate[Show[Graphics[{
    Line[{{0, 0}, {1, .5 Sin[t]}, {2, 0}}],
    Line[{{-.1, -1}, {-.1, 1}}],
    Triangle[{{-.1, -.1}, {-.1, .1}, {0, 0}}]
    }]], {t, 0, 10}]`

Comment: You have a typo:  (\[Phi]2^'')

Answer (score 2):

I have corrected your definition of $\varphi_3$, so that the final end of the third beam is constrained to horizontal movement.

```
\[Phi]3[t_] := ArcSin[-((L1 Sin[\[Phi]1[t]] + L2 Sin[\[Phi]2[t]])/L3)];
X0 = 0;
Y0 = 0;

X1 = L1 Cos[\[Phi]1[t]];
Y1 = L1 Sin[\[Phi]1[t]];
X2 = X1 + L2 Cos[\[Phi]2[t]];
Y2 = Y1 + L2 Sin[\[Phi]2[t]];
X3 = X2 + (L3 Cos[\[Phi]3[t]]);
Y3 = Y2 + (L3 Sin[\[Phi]3[t]]);


Animate[Evaluate@Show[Graphics[{
      Line[{{0, 0}, {X1, Y1}, {X2, Y2}, {X3, Y3}}],
      Line[{{-1, -4}, {-1, 4}}],
      Line[{{9, -1}, {15, -1}}],
      Disk[{X1, Y1}, .1], Disk[{X2, Y2}, .1],
      EdgeForm[Black], White,
      Triangle[{{-1, -1}, {-1, 1}, {0, 0}}],
      Triangle[{{X3 - 1, -1}, {X3, 0}, {X3 + 1, -1}}]
      }] /. (sol // First), PlotRange -> {{-2, 15}, {-2, 2}}], {t, 0, 
  10}, AnimationRate -> .5]
```

[image: Animation]

Comment: thank you this solution is very helpful.  Would it also be possible to add a roller support on the right side that allows motion in X dimension olny?

Comment: Sure, but can you just write down first how the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the joints are expressed by the angles $\varphi$?

Comment: These are the coordinates in XY expressed with angles. They are placed where the torsion springs are. [X1(Kt1)=L1*Cos(φ1), Y1Kt1)=L1*Sin(φ1), X2(Kt2)=L1*Cos(φ1)+L2*Cos(φ2), Y2Kt1)=L1*Sin(φ1)+L2*Sin(φ2)].

Comment: This is the same way as I have defined the coordinates in my attempt. But as you can see, the right end of the third beam also has some vertical ($y$) movement. According to your drawing, this should not be happening, because it is constrained to horizontal movement. So, there is probably a mistake somewhere, either in the differential equations or in the definition of coordinates ...

Comment: The rotation of second and the third beam is revolving around the centre of mass of each beam so the coordinates change to X2 = X1 + (L2 Cos[\[Phi]2[t]])/2; X3 = X2 + (L3 Cos[\[Phi]3[t]])/2. This is likely the coordinate problem as im fairly certain the DE's are correct.

Comment: I think I have found the correct definition of $\varphi_3$ and the coordinates, so I have edited my first answer. Let me know if this is what you have been looking for.

Comment: This is how the animation should look, however the coordinates are still not correct. The correct coordinates definitions are:  X2 = X1 + (L2 Cos[\[Phi]2[t]])/2; Y2 = Y1 + (L2 Sin[\[Phi]2[t]])/2, X3 = X1+L2 Cos[\[Phi]2[t]] + ((L3 Cos[\[Phi]3[t]]))/2, Y3 = Y1+L2 Sin[\[Phi]2[t]]+ (L3 Sin[\[Phi]3[t]]))/2. Also the definition of [Phi]3 is somewhat strange to me.

Comment: I haven't explicitly mentioned this before: as you can see, I draw the beams by providing their _endpoints_. That is why there is no $1/2$ in my coordinates. Your coordinates provide the positions of beam _midpoints_. 

As for the angle: if angles are measured in absolute frame (from the horizontal) as sketched in your drawing, then I think my derivation is correct. The $y$-component of the last beam has to be 0 (at the same height as the left support): $y_1+y_2+y_3=0 \implies L_1 \sin\varphi_1 + L_2 \sin\varphi_2 + L_3 \sin\varphi_3 = 0$.

Comment: Okay now almost everything is as I have imagined it. However have you drawn the first beam to revolve around its mass centre aswell? Because it should revolve around The support on the left.

Comment: As you can see in the code (and in the animation), the left end of the first beam has fixed coordinates $(x_0, y_0) = (0,0)$. This means that the first beam is rotating around the support on the left.

Comment: Oh okay then thats about everything. This is the exact model I've been looking for. Thank you you've been a massive help. I do have one final question though. When i run the code on my computer the program mathematica becomes extremely laggy. Would it be possible to smooth out the animation?

Comment: You can precompute the frames: `frames = Table[Evaluate@Show[...], {t, 0, 10, .1}]` and then use `ListAnimate[frames]`. You can also export the animation to a .gif or a movie file with `Export["animation.gif", frames]`.

Comment: Now the animation runs smoothly. Again thanks for all your help